# How to use fold in polars?

Tags: python-polars

in the API document.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [2, 1, 3],
        "b": [1, 2, 3],
        "c": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    }
)
df.fold(lambda s1, s2: s1 + s2)
```

what is `s1` and `s2` refer to?

In user guide:

```py
out = df.select(
    pl.fold(acc=pl.lit(0), f=lambda acc, x: acc + x, exprs=pl.col("*")).alias("sum"),
)
print(out)
```

what is `acc`?

Comment: Thanks for the good advice, I have edited my question, so when I pose question in github they say I should pose it in osf. Maybe I should post in two separate communities in different formats (although that seems a bit trivial).

Answer (score 1):

Both these syntaxes will return similar results (albeit not exactly identical, especially with regards to their return types).

```py
import polars as pl


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df: pl.DataFrame = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "a": [2, 1, 3],
            "b": [1, 2, 3],
            "c": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        }
    )
    r1: pl.Series = df.fold(lambda s1, s2: s1 + s2)
    r2: pl.DataFrame = df.select(pl.fold(
        acc=pl.lit(0),
        function=lambda acc, x: acc + x, # the f keyword is deprecated
        exprs=pl.col("*")
    ))
    print(f"{r1}\n{type(r1)}")
    print(f"{r2}\n{type(r2)}")
```

`r1`:

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'a' [f64]
[
    4.0
    5.0
    9.0
]
<class 'polars.internals.series.series.Series'>
```

`r2`:

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ f64 │
╞═════╡
│ 4.0 │
│ 5.0 │
│ 9.0 │
└─────┘
<class 'polars.internals.dataframe.frame.DataFrame'>
```

These are not the same methods! The first one is `polars.DataFrame.fold` while the second is `polars.fold`.

That said, the one I find easiest to use is the second one, with the `acc` that is bothering you. This parameter is the [*accumulator*](https://www.arothuis.nl/posts/accumulators-and-folds/), where you will accumulate the results of your operation, defined in the `function`. Said operation will be iteratively performed with your accumulator as first parameter, and a cell in the second, over each cell.